Unable to click element on job pages on linkedin using Selenium
I am unable to click on the "easy apply" button on any job page with an "easy apply" option on linkedin.
After navigating to any of the job pages using selenium driver, I have tried the following using both the text and full xpath:
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[normalize-space()='Easy Apply']"))).click()

and
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[normalize-space(.)='Easy Apply']"))).click()

and
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/main/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/button"))).click()

For all three, I get selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException
How do I solve this, please help?

Your selectors seem's wrong.
This one work to click on the button that you are looking for:
button_apply = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[button/@class='jobs-apply-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--3 artdeco-button--primary ember-view']")

This is the full code that i use for this issue :
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Set implicit-wait to wait to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available.
driver.implicitly_wait(15) 

# Open the website. Manual connection to Linkedin website is required here.
driver.get(r'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/collections/recommended/?currentJobId=3970401749&eBP=CwEAAAGRIvZBxDHi5DSUXb9ts2v5F0VXmSKobS7tfh6OsBkVfZDP1b20VMNuQGwnHOh2OXY1mR4aa23XMzFkuJ1zEwJ7gJaF1mHkHdI7goN4Uv1E-OmAEyaslvRKHVAjjQmTu9uHFfFK45aw0IucpazTUYzkBHVic6IEgKCInp9wKwpm3vJ6DQy4CpfMS1f6KwUo2E5DGP-7H6aoz7ABmxNHVe3on5k4wlLRo0Q99aBRiXmGAkaP_UcIvPgmvzj6RBSRvjiZ-qbCBqGb4v_qXdjQpwKzZfxITP3N3PfNPe6CvLvgJcQcKPGNJa3vWk9F0zqv4LPfiPk86mTgoQCxoANHloAhnL1geV3kGdSPeo9251V7VulRucRmWPmsY9Iaii8FGAK7udozeVR0xkzVB5YZuiy2y764HhtT1Wb_jse8ey9yQ7mWzHVfSbNFm4ddYe-uZktccw&refId=YHM%2BbmCkMZ5cg8FuYEt%2F6A%3D%3D&trackingId=cKVa8%2FV%2BrV3nLG33mwzD%2FA%3D%3D')

try :
    # Find the button
    button_apply = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[button/@class='jobs-apply-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--3 artdeco-button--primary ember-view']")

    # Printing text of the button for testing purpose 
    print(button_apply.text) # Easy Apply

    # Click on the button
    button_apply.click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

Source : Locating-XPATH-Elements, implicit-waits

Did you use ChatGPT or another AI to write this answer?

Not at all but i take that as a compliment

You shouldn't, it was not meant to be a compliment. It's more of an acknowledgement of SO's quality going down the drain, with answers generated by AI and users like me not caring enough to actually report them. You can deny all you want, some of us are a bit harder to fool. It doesn't matter anyway. Good luck.

Sorry Barry but your comments are rude and unusfull. If you trust that I have used an AI you can report my answer like i reports your comment.
